# How to rebuild a Verity/PeopleSoft index?

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft, verity

We have a Verity K2 V6.1 file-based search system as implemented in RedDot LiveServer V3.1.1.

The `VerityDB` folder (appears to hold search index) contains over 17,000 “.bif” (Verity’s ‘Bulk Insert File’ format) files that appear to contain add/delete/change instructions for updating the index. We know that as of about 4 weeks ago new BIF files were no longer incorporated into the live search index.

Translation: we have web pages that exist, but our search engine index doesn't know about them. We traced it back to this issue with the Verity index.

Two part question:

1. What’s the correct process to rebuild the Verity index
2. Can we safely eliminate old BIF files (the files go back 9 YEARS in age) with the hope that newer BIF files are applied?

A complete answer should list all steps to rebuild the Verity index (screenshots would be appreciated, but not required!)